# Print HTML Page Twitter bootstrap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap

I have a show page /invoices/show that displays contents of my Invoice

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>
<div class="row">
<div class="span7">
    <h2 style="text-align:center;"> CONSTRUCTION LTD </h2>
        <h3 style="text-align:center;">OHIO</h3>
            <address style="text-align:center;"> Plot 10<br/>
            </address>

        <h3 style="text-decoration:underline; text-align:center;"> UTILITY BILL </h3>
            <h4 style="text-decoration:underline; text-align:center;"> TAX INVOICE        </h4>

        <table>
            <td valign="top" align="left">
                <div style="float:left; width:450px;">No:&nbsp; <%= @invoice.id  %></div>
                <div style="float:right"> Date:&nbsp; <%= @invoice.invoice_date  %></div>
            </td>
        </table>
            <P></P>
            <P></P>
    <div>To: <%= @invoice.customer.name%></div>
        <p></p>


<table class="table table-bordered table-condensed">
<thead>
<tr class="success">
  <th><label class="control-label">Description</label></th>
  <th><label class="control-label">Rate</label></th>
  <th><label class="control-label">Tax</label></th>
  <th><label class="control-label">Amount</label></th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<% @invoice.invoice_items.each do | item| %>
  <tr class="controls"> 
    <td><%= item.description %></td>
    <td><%= item.rate %></td>
    <td><%= item.tax_amount %></td>
    <td><%= item.amount %></td>     
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td colspan="3" align="left"><strong>TOTAL:</strong></td>
      <td colspan="1"><%= item.amount %></td>
  </tr>
    <% end %>
</tbody>
</table>


<div class="row">
<div class="span3">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td> <b>For Landlord</b></td></tr>
            <tr> <td>Approved by:</td></tr>
            <tr> <td>Sign:</td></tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

<div class="span3" style="position: relative; align:left; left:150px;">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td> <b>For Tenant</b></td></tr>
            <tr> <td>Approved by:</td></tr>
            <tr> <td>Sign:</td></tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>
 </div>
</div>
<br/>
<br />
<div>
<small><strong>Terms and Conditions</strong></small>
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><%= Settings.invoice_terms%></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
<br />

<div class="form actions">
<p>
    <%= link_to t('.edit', :default => t("helpers.links.edit")),
                edit_invoice_path, :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
</p>
</div>  
</div>
</div>
```

In my application.html.erb, I have this for CSS

```
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
```

More to that, my application file has a nav-bar element.

I am trying to print the Invoices/show.html.erb page by going to the print option in a browser, however, I do not want it to include the nav-bar element in my application.html.erb file and the edit button in invoices/show.html.

I am using Twitter bootstrap, how can i go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one solution I've thought of:

What you can do is, in your `show` view (or the application layout) add a predicate:

```
if params[:controller] == "invoice" && params[:action] == "show"
  # do or show whatever you want
end
```

Or you could do add a different layout to your `views/layouts` folder. Then in your `controllers/invoice_controller`

```
def show
  # ...
  render layout: 'a_different_layout_for_invoices'
end
```

Comment: What I actually did was add a print action in my controller and set the layout to false. In the View, all i did was inline styling and wala....it worked